# Operation timed out installing OpenCV on mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv, openexr

I want to install opencv for python on my mac. While I follow a tutorial on website

I typed this command on my command console.

```
brew install opencv
```

That operation installs every dependant frameworks on my computer, one of them is 'openexr'.

However, this installing operation throws out this error

```
==> Installing opencv dependency: openexr
==> Downloading http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/openexr/openexr-2.1.0.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (7) Failed to connect to public.p-knowledge.co.jp port 80: Operation timed out
Error: Failed to download resource "openexr"
Download failed: http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/openexr/openexr-2.1.0.tar.gz
```

So I also tried to download that file to the website above, http://download.savannah.gnu.org and OpenEXR official website, but I think that link is blocked or something has problem.

Is there any solution to install OpenCV for python on my mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, Here is my answer.

In short, this problem happens when you are just upgrade Yosemite OS X in old brew

So, you might have

```
brew update
```

first, and then

```
brew install homebrew/science/opencv
```

Then it will start install openCV on your mac.